# I can't use malicous reflection to view values of private fields

Tags: java, security, reflection, exploit

I can get the value of the protected field, but the private field throws `java.lang.IllegalAccessException`. I think I know why I'm getting this exception, but how is reflection used to exploit the contents of private fields, how do I get around this?

**Programmer Hat is on**
 I have created the following Vulnerable class in a netbeans project. I have made a Jar file to distribute it.

```
public class Vulnerable {
    private int privateSecret;
    protected int protectedSecret;
    int secret;

    public Vulnerable() {
    this.protectedSecret = 11;
    this.privateSecret = 22;
    this.secret = 33;
    }
}
```

**Malicious Hacker Hat is now on**
I want to know private hidden fields and I want to know what they contain.
I have the Jar file and I have imported it into my Exploit project.

The following class extends Vulnerable and uses reflection to list fields and try to access the values.

```
public class ExpliotSubClass extends VulnerableCode.Vulnerable {

    public List<Field> protectedList = new LinkedList<Field>();
    public List<Field> privateList = new LinkedList<Field>();

    public void lists() {
        Field[] declaredFields = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field field : declaredFields) {
            int modifiers = field.getModifiers();
            if (Modifier.isPrivate(modifiers)) {
                privateList.add(field);
                System.out.println("Private = " + field.getName());
            } else if (Modifier.isProtected(modifiers)) {
                protectedList.add(field);
                System.out.println("Protected= " + field.getName());
            }
        }
    }


    public Object get(Field field) {
        try {
            return field.get(this);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ExpliotSubClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                                                                  null,
                                                                  ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ExpliotSubClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
                                                                  null,
                                                                  ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to access private field you have to set it as accessible:

```
field.setAccessible(true);
```

Comment: HA! that is easy, I spent allot longer formulating and constructing that question, than what was needed to answer it. :( lol

Comment: @AnotherCompilerError It's easy when you know where's the problem :)

Comment: If I had further questions about this topic is best to ask here or open another question?

Comment: @AnotherCompilerError If the question is, "how do I prevent this?" then that is definitely deserving of a second question.

Comment: if it's not connected to accessing private fields, I would recommend a new question (so others having that same problem can find it later)

Answer (score 1):

in this lists() method, you should add the following code, before adding the field object to the privateList.

-field.setAccessible(true);

That is the code for the lists method will become

public void lists() {
        Field[] declaredFields = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredFields();

```
    for (Field field : declaredFields) {
        int modifiers = field.getModifiers();
        if (Modifier.isPrivate(modifiers)) {
            field.setAccessible(true);//Add this
            privateList.add(field);
            System.out.println("Private = " + field.getName());
        } else if (Modifier.isProtected(modifiers)) {
            protectedList.add(field);
            System.out.println("Protected= " + field.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Now run your code. It will work.

Comment: is the class field accessible or only just the when referenced by that particular field object in memory, which has now been placed in the list.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `.jar` can you just decompile it and then parse the `.java` file to get the info you need?

Comment: -1?  I thought it was a valid work around, even if it wasn't in the spirit of the question.

Comment: Not what the asker wants to accomplish; the secret might not be available at compile time. Also, `.jar`s contain `.class` files, not `.java` files, which must then be decompiled to get something approximating, but not identical to, the original `.java`

Comment: Yeah, i said to decompile it.  My understanding is the .java files obtained would have a list of the hardcoded values as well as all the members of the class

Comment: You can get the default value, but the simplest and correct answer is Kuba's

Comment: It only works if the value is hardcoded; most secret values are not.

Comment: yeah, his answer is better.  I just said what i would have done in a pinch ;-)

Comment: +1 If a "malicious hacker" is able to remove the security checks, they are likely to also be able to change the class file. It may well be easier to  do the latter.